# vim in ConEmu is showing all text in bold

Tags: vim, conemu, cmder

I'm using vim in ConEmu (with cmder) on Windows, and for some reason all the text is displayed in bold.

[image: All the text is bold in vim]

It's only happening in vim, just in ConEmu the text is regular.

[image: Text is not bold in ConEmu itself]

The boldness started when I added the following section to my `.vimrc` in order to get color schemes working under ConEmu (based on the [docs](https://conemu.github.io/en/VimXterm.html#requirements)):

```
if !has("gui_running")
    set term=xterm
    set t_Co=256
    let &t_AB="\e[48;5;%dm"
    let &t_AF="\e[38;5;%dm"
endif
```

If I remove this section, then the text is not bold any more (but the color schemes are not working).

The color scheme I'm using does not matter, the text is bold no matter which one I use.

**Update**: I just noticed by running `:version` that some text is actually not bold, when the version info is printed:

[image: The version info is not completely bold]

It seems to be pretty random what is bold and what isn't, and it even changes if I resize the window.

**Update 2**: @Maximus mentioned that I can log the raw ANSI input ConEmu receives, and I tried to do that.

I opened a test file which contains the text "This is a dummy text.", which is displayed in bold:

[image]

And this is the input I see in the logs: `[48;5;0mThis is a dummy text.`
I'm not sure how to interpret this. I'm looking at the description [here](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php), based on which `5` should mean "Blink on", but the text is not blinking, it's just bold, which should be the code `1`. Anyone knows better how to interpret this?

I'm using PowerShell
ConEmu version: 161206 [64] stable (and I also tried it with the latest alpha, 171217)
VIM version: 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Nov 11 2017 23:02:03), MS-Windows 64-bit console version, Included patches: 1-1290

Comment: ConEmu version? Vim version? Terminal modes?

Comment: @Maximus Updated the question with the version numbers, and also with an another screenshot, because I realized that some text is not actually bold for some reason. You also mention **Terminal modes**. Where can I find that information?

Comment: Status bar -> Terminal mode.

Comment: You are running a year old build! [Old Builds](https://conemu.github.io/en/OldBuild.html)

Comment: @Maximus I'm using the latest stable version (https://www.fosshub.com/ConEmu.html).

Comment: @Maximus but I tried it now with the latest alpha, 171217, and I'm experiencing the same behavior.

Comment: ConEmu has an option to dump all ANSI sequences to file. https://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsFeatures.html#id2679

Comment: @Maximus thanks for the tip, I did that, but I'm at a bit of a loss about how to interpret the output. I added the details to the end of the question.

Comment: Upload the log file to gist without changes. The snippet you provided is not enough.

Comment: @Maximus I uploaded the full log [here](https://gist.github.com/markvincze/5541d0029c13eea8520f88b8dda464f1). It is the logs for a short session, only starting a new ConEmu window, opening the `test.txt` file with `vim`, and exiting.